# Regular expression extractor with Inter-Thread communication

Tags: jmeter

I am using Inter Thread communication post processor to store values extracted using regular expression extractor. But, i am running into an issue when the request fails and the regular expression extrator has no value against the variable. Example: I am storing an ID against a variable  ${Emp-ID} in the Inter communication post processor. When the request has failed and no value is returned from the regular expression extrator, but, ${EmpID} is stored in the queue. Is there a way to just ignore and not store any value?

[Inter communication post processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVwxB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest is switching to the [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead, example code:

```
if (vars.get('Emp-ID') != null) {
    kg.apc.jmeter.modifiers.FifoMap.getInstance().put('EMP-Queue', vars.get('Emp-ID'))
}
```

where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 test elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).